# Cannot find symbol error in solr integration with java

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am beginner in solr i am trying to query solr from the java application (on play framework). 
I have included the following jar files to my lib directory

```
apache-solr-solrj-*.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-io-1.4.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.5.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.5.jar
```

as instructed in http://www.solrtutorial.com/solrj-tutorial.html

and my code is

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocumentList;

 public static Result getRecipesAndVariants(String searchString){
    JsonNode jnode = null;
 HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/dbcollection");

SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery("fiction");

query.setFields("id","title","author");
query.setStart(0);    
query.set("defType", "edismax");

QueryResponse response = solr.query(query);
SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();
  for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
  System.out.println("from solr : "+results.get(i));
}
```

I am getting the error as 
 error: cannot find symbol            HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/dbcollection");
Kindly Help please

Comment: Are you using any IDE, like eclipse?

Comment: No i am not using any ide

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because of your jar file `apache-solr-solrj-*.jar` 
You have to add as full name rather using regex.

Comment: I am sorry thats a typo the file i have included is apache-solr-solrj-1.4.0.jar

Comment: is it still not working?, are you using correct classpath ?. Can you put your command to compile the code.?

Answer (score 0):

`HttpSolrServer` is not even part of [solrj 1.4](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-solrj/1.4.0/) api. I have attached the screenshot from grepcode. Why don't you use the latest or higher version of solrj api. [solrj 4.0](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-solrj/4.0.0/) contains the `HttpSolrServer` class.

[image]